# Reduction link in category

Tags: php, wordpress

If i create new category, for example **article** i have all posts in this category on link:

```
http://www.mypage.com/category/article
```

how can i make:

```
http://www.mypage.com/article
```

without "category"?

Comment: Read up on mod_rewrite for Apache, other servers have similar mechanisms. Here's a guide http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I have used Wordpress, but if I'm not mistaken, you should be able to edit your URL in wp-admin. You can use [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) page to help you locate the section in the admin.

You would use a URL structure as such...

```
%postname%
```

That will remove the category from the URL. Just keep in mind that changing this could mess up the permalinks for any previous posts. You can either modify the permalinks in wp-admin or through the database using a tool such as phpMyAdmin. Alternatively, I believe there are plugins that will redirect old permalinks, but like I said, it's a been a while since the last time I used Wordpress.